# URL inside php get variable is not redirecting. It gives 404 error

Tags: php, apache, http, redirect, http-status-code-404

Recently I moved my hosting from godaddy to hostgator.

I have a download page in my website (getintopc.com) called download_direct.php What it does it accepts the URL parameters e.g.

http://getintopc.com/download_direct.php?c=http://trial.autodesk.com/SWDLDNET3/2014/AMECH_PP/DLM/AutoCAD_Mechanical_2014_English_Win_64bit_dlm.sfx.exe

So inside the download_direct.php I had simple code for HTTP meta redirect to url which is in PHP Get variable "C"

But now this code is not working on new hosting package. It simply gives 404 error. However the page exists. This can be verified by typing getintopc.com/download_direct.php

But it seems argument passed in variable is not being accepted as per code logic. The code is not changed. It was working on godaddy.com

Please help me

Comment: What URL is it actually sending you to?

Comment: post your code so we can review.

Comment: I just tried the link in your post and it successfully began downloading AutoCAD.

Answer (score 1):

I think You need to encode the redirect url:

```
$c = urlencode("http://trial.autodesk.com/SWDLDNET3/2014/AMECH_PP/DLM/AutoCAD_Mechanical_2014_English_Win_64bit_dlm.sfx.exe");
$url = "http://getintopc.com/download_direct.php?c={$c}";
```

If the value of c is not encoded, then the whole url becomes invalid.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out `$_GET['c']`. Maybe PHP isn't reading your parameter correctly.